# How to use the command line to get a list of peers from a BitTorrent tracker

Tags: file-sharing, bittorrent, protocols

Given that I have the infohash of a torrent and the URL of a BitTorrent tracker (e.g. `udp://tracker.example.com/announce`), how do I use the command line to get all the IP addresses of peers that the tracker knows about? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `transmission-cli` you can run `transmission-cli <infohash> <(tracker) URL>` and then `transmission-cli -l`.

Comment: I have transmission-cli 2.94. There is no `-l` command line option. What version of transmission-cli are you using?

Comment: Sorry, try `transmission-remote -l`.

Comment: `transmission-cli <infohash> <(tracker) URL>` is invalid too. Error message: "ERROR: Unrecognized torrent ...".